# Multiplayer game over ham radio digital link?

Tags: united-states, legal

Would it be legal to play a multiplayer video game over a ham radio link? Both players are hams, and their call signs will be transmitted in the link.

Comment: Already done, if you're willing to consider computer chess a "video game".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of ham activities resemble games and contests.

Under FCC rules, there are very few restrictions on actives like this.
Basically, it just has to follow the normal amateur radio rules.

Some relevant ones are:

- Obviously identification rules must be obeyed.
- The content should be family friendly, since anyone could be listening.
- Nobody should get paid (no prizes of monetary value...)
- The band plan including allowed modes should be followed.
- No encryption...encoding methods should be published.

Comment: Many modern games encrypt the over-the-wire protocol to prevent cheating and almost none of them publish their encoding methods.  Open source games would be the notable exception.

Comment: @chicks I'll be developing the games, so I can be sure that there is no encryption, and they will be open source.

Comment: That is awesome to hear!  Please drop us a link when you get something going.